# Python: taking the dot product of vector with numpy

Tags: python, vector, numpy

I have taken the dot product of vectors in `Python` many of times, but for some reason, one such `np.dot()` command isn't working.

---

```
#!/usr/bin/env ipython                                                              

import numpy as np
from numpy import linalg as LA
from scipy.optimize import fsolve

Re = 1.496e8  #  semi-major axis of the Earth 
Te = 365.25 * 24.0 * 3600.0  #  period of the Earth in sec
mus = 132712000000.0  #  grav param of the Sun 

def f(a):
    return (2 * np.pi / np.sqrt(mus) * np.sqrt(a ** 3) - Te * 2.0 / 3.0)


a = fsolve(f, 100000000)

e = Re / a - 1

rp = a * (1 - e)
h = np.sqrt(2 * mus) * np.sqrt(Re * rp / (Re + rp))
vE = np.sqrt(mus / Re)
vp = h / Re
vinf = vE - vp

alt = 500.0  #  the flyby distance                                                  
rph = 6378 + alt  #  radius at periapsis of the flyby hyperbola                     
mue = 398600.0  #  grav param of the Earth                                          

eh = 1 + rph * vinf ** 2 / mue

beta = np.arccos(1.0 / eh)

delta = 2.0 * beta

vpvec = np.array([0, -vp, 0])
vinfoutvec = vinf * np.array([-np.sin(delta), np.cos(delta)])
vhpostvec = np.array([vinfoutvec[0], vinfoutvec[1] + vpvec[1]])

r0 = np.array([-Re, 0, 0])
v0 = np.array([vhpostvec[0], vhpostvec[1], 0])
h0vec = np.cross(r0, v0)
h0 = LA.norm(h0vec)

e2vec = np.cross(v0, h0vec) / mus - r0 / LA.norm(r0)
e2 = LA.norm(e2vec)
nu0 = np.arccos(np.dot(e2vec, np.array([1.0, 0, 0])) / e2)

#taking the dot product of the vector, specifying the vector location, 
#and pulling the actual coordinate options

#nupost = (np.arccos(np.dot(r0, e2vec) / (Re * e2)) * 180.0 / np.pi)                
#nupost = (np.arccos(r0[0] * e2vec[0] / (Re * e2)) * 180.0 / np.pi) 
#nupost = (np.arccos(-Re * 0.30029169 / (Re * e2)) * 180.0 / np.pi)
```

---

1. I checked that the vectors were of the same dimension and we have that `r0` is `1x3` and so is the `e2vec`.  However, whenever I attempt to take the dot product of these two vectors, I receive

   ```
   ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
   <ipython-input-13-40977131af32> in <module>()
   ----> 1 execfile(r'/home/dustin/test.py') # PYTHON-MODE

   /home/dustin/test.py in <module>()
        26
        27 #nupost = (np.arccos(-Re * 0.30029169 / (Re * e2)) * 180.0 / np.pi)
   ---> 28 nupost = (np.arccos(np.dot(r0, e2vec) / (Re * e2)) * 180.0 / np.pi)
        29 #nupost = (np.arccos(r0[0] * e2vec[0] / (Re * e2)) * 180.0 / np.pi)
        30

   ValueError: matrices are not aligned
   ```
2. Then I tried specifying the vector component `r0[0]` and `e2vec[0]` where multiplying these produces a `1x3` vector with the correct answer in the first position.  However, I shouldn't be receiving a vector here.

   ```
   In [14]: The eccentricity vector of the new ellipse is [[ 0.30029169  0.14176274  \
   0.        ]]
   The post flyby true anomaly is [ 154.72877834  115.27122166   90.        ]
   ```
3. If I just pull the actual values, everything works perfectly.

I am not a `Python` expert, but why isn't the dot product working in case 1 and why isn't specifying the vector component working in case 2?  In my example, I have used both the dot product vector component specification previously with no such issues.

Comment: Can you include the declarations of all your variables in the code? That would make helping you a lot easier.

Comment: Or better yet, just remove most of your code except the failing line, as well as prints of all involved variables right before the line.

Comment: Are your vectors 1-dimensional (shape `(3,)`), or 2-dimensional (shape `(1, 3)`)?

Comment: I only meant remove it from the post. The problem is as pointed out that `e2vec` has shape `(1, 3)`. The quickest fix is to do `e2vec.ravel()` before passed to `np.dot`.

Comment: @downvoters thanks for providing insight to your down votes. I don't see what the problem is.  I came across a problem, tried different avenues of approach, the last one worked, and I wanted to know why the other two were failing.  So examining the down vote synopsis: the question is clear, I would guess the question is useful because others probably have had this problem too, and I attempted 2 separate work around solutions so I did put in effort.  So what is the deal since illogical down votes is a `SO` anomaly compared to the other sites?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks as though `e2vec` is 2D with the shape `(1, 3)`. You need to flatten it before passing it to `np.dot`, which you can do as follows:

```
nupost = (np.arccos(np.dot(r0, e2vec.ravel()) / (Re * e2)) * 180.0 / np.pi)
```

Comment: I am confused about 1D with shape (3,) and 2D with shape `(1,3)`.  The vectors are both `1x3` so how is `e2vec` of shape 2D?

Comment: The one with shape `(3,)` isn't 1x3 any more than the 2-d one is 1x3x3. Numpy arrays support any number of dimensions (even 0!); `dot` is only dot product for 1-dimensional arrays.

Comment: When I say 2D here, I mean number of dimensions in the numpy array and not in a mathematical sense. With that definition in mind, shape `(3,)` is 1D and shape `(1, 3)` is 2D, which is why you need to convert `e2vec` only.

Comment: You can also use numpy.vdot.